# Deleting and recreating the same association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model created through devise, a stock model (generated through a scaffold) so I can create a stocks database with my own custom prices, and a UserStock model to establish an association between the two. Everything seems to run fine in both my UI and my console.

Here's the catch.
I have a delete method tied to a button that is configured in my _list.html.erb which displays all stocks in the user's portfolio. When I delete it the first time, (remove stock from my portfolio) it works fine. When I add the stock again to my portfolio, works fine of course. But the deletion the second time does not work. 
Say, for example, my user ID is 1. My UserStock association creates an association between user_id 1 and stock_id 1 (say stock with id 1 is Google). This is stored in UserStock id 1. When I delete this association and recreate the same, it gets stored in UserStock id 2 (a brand new association). But when I try to delete it again, I'm unable to do so. My rails console indicates this error in my UserStock controller.

This is the error that pops up: Record Not Found in UserStocksController#destroy

```
  def set_user_stock
   @user_stock= UserStock.find(params[:id])  
  end
```

EDIT:  Sure, here's my view and the required models:

```
            <% if @user.id = current_user.id %>
            <td>
            <%=link_to "Delete", user_stock_path(user_stock), :method 
            => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" },
            :class => "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
            </td>
            <% end %>
```

user.rb

```
     has_many :user_stocks
     has_many :stocks, through: :user_stocks
     def can_add_stock?(ticker_symbol)
       !stock_already_added?(ticker_symbol)
     end

     def stock_already_added?(ticker_symbol)
       stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
       return false unless stock
       user_stocks.where(stock_id: stock.id).exists?
     end
```

stock.rb

```
has_many :user_stocks
has_many :users, through: :user_stocks
def self.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
    where(ticker: ticker_symbol).first
end
```

user_stock.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :stock
```

Comment: Which view are you on and what does the code look like for that view?  I will say that it is unusual you would have a controller for a join table.  Usually you would use something like the Users controller for this and find the UserStock with `@user.user_stocks` and you can attach your delete to that.

Comment: You need to show us your view, as well as the relevant models for us to help you.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I know it's unusual. It's just for the client's convenience (since it's a stock trading game, it's easier for them to see what stocks the participants tracking through this table). But it should work nonetheless. I've updated my code above.

Comment: "This is stored in UserStock id 1. When I delete this association and recreate the same, it gets stored in UserStock id 2 (a brand new association)." Thats how auto-incrementing database columns work, its a ticker that goes up every time you insert a row. Not a count of the number of rows.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. The problem, however, lies in user_stock being called in the view. If I inspect the user_stock, it is retrieving the Stock name,symbol,price and id instead of the user_stock association id. That's why the delete request isn't working, it's querying the wrong ID to delete. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are attempting to do is iterate through the stocks owned by a user you should start on the `user_stocks` end instead of the `stocks` association:

```
<% @user.user_stocks.each do |user_stock| %>
  <td><%= user_stock.stock.ticker %></td>
  <td><%= user_stock.stock.name %></td>
  <% if @user.id = current_user.id %>
  <td>
    <%= link_to "Delete", user_stock_path(user_stock), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
  </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get an 'undefined local method or variable "us" ' in your <td></td> views

Comment: Hi max. I feel like I've got the logic now. I think this is the right path, where I iterate the do loop through the user_stocks association. But I'm getting a console error "undefined method or variable us". How do I resolve this?

Comment: Ahh, now I'm getting a user_stock method not defined. I've run into this problem before as well. May I know how to resolve this? I reckon it's something to do with my association setup or foreign key references? (I've set up both correctly afaik)

Comment: Are you using `user.user_stock` instead of the plural `user.user_stocks`?

Comment: Again typo on my part - should be `user_stock.stock`. Time for bed.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I've been struggling endlessly on this. xD